# What is the most reliable and efficient way to ensure Twilio sends a chain of messages in order?

Tags: python, django, twilio, twilio-api

I'm attempting to lay the foundation for a relatively simple messaging system using Twilio API and its Python wrapper. Users should be able to text a keyword and receive back a string of responses.

The problem is, using the suggested HttpResponse() package from Twilio's documentation, when I loop through the messages to add them to a response chain, they hit Twilio in a block, and sends the service sends them in a seemingly random order, which really compromises the readability of the block.

Here's a simplified version of the loop I'm running in Django to create the response:

```
@csrf_exempt
def inbox(request)
   if request.method == "POST":
        # Interpret the keyword in the incoming message
        data = request.POST
        messageBody = data['Body'].lower()

        # Check if it matches a valid keyword
        targetTrigger = Keyword.objects.get(trigger_word=messageBody)

        # Pull the appropriate responses
        messageChain = Message.objects.filter(keyword_answers=targetTrigger)

        # Create the messaging response
        resp = MessagingResponse()

        # Populate it with messages
        for sms in messageChain:
            resp.message(sms)

        # Send them to Twilio
        return HttpResponse(str(resp))
```

I've glossed over the try and error catches for the sake of readability. And like I said, this sends the messages in a seemingly random order, with shorter messages appearing to send through to my iPhone first more of the time. Not always, but enough for me to need to rethink this method.

Strangely there's little in the documentation about sending multiple messages in a SMS HttpResponse, though I imagine it's a common use case. The alternative I was considering is sending back a blank HttpResponse to simply acknowledge to Twilio the message was received successfully, and then using its regular one-by-one sending method with my for loop. That seems a little less efficient, but I need accuracy in the order the messages send.

Any suggestions? Twilio developer evangelists, I know you all are out here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Twilio, [this cannot be done.](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223134247-Can-my-SMS-messages-arrive-in-order-)  as they simply do not have control over the delivery process.

> Twilio cannot guarantee that SMS messages sent from your Twilio phone number will arrive in order. While we will send the SMS messages you pass to us in the order that you’ve queued them, the SMS messages are delivered individually with no association to each other. The order of delivery depends on the carrier.
>
> To help your users understand the order of your messages, we recommend
> that you append a page reference following each message, for example
> 1/3, 2/3, 3/3.

In SMS, the shortest message is typically sent the fastest. You could potentially design your messages to be ordered by size. That might reduce the frequency of error.

Another option might be to bundle them all into one large 1600 character message and having the carrier deal with breaking it apart. It would depend on whether concatenated SMS is reliably supported by carriers in your client base. That might deal with the order issue.

Comment: Mm I missed that in their troubleshooting section when I scanned. Not an ideal solution. But we'll find a way to make it work. Thanks!